# Compilation error: Can not convert boolean into an int

Tags: java, compiler-errors, static-typing

The problem is as follows:

1. Create a program named PrimeGenerator. Write a method isPrime that
   determines if a number is prime.

`public static boolean isPrime(long number)`

2. In `main()` create an array named `primes` that will contain the first 200 prime
   numbers. Find the primes by calling the `isPrime(long)` method, and store each prime in
   the array. Then display the primes in the command prompt window, ten to a line.
   The primes must be displayed in right-aligned columns. Be sure to label your
   output and to comment your code. (Java)

So far all I have is this:

```
public class PrimeGenerator 
{

    public static int[] work = new int[201];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 200;
        int[] array = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
        for (int numberList = 1; numberList < array.length; numberList++)
            array[numberList] = isPrime(6L);
        for (int numberList = 1; numberList < array.length; numberList++)
            System.out.printf("%5d%8d%n", numberList, array[numberList]);
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(long number){
        for(long gg = 3; gg * gg <= number; gg++){
            if(number % gg ==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect each element of your array to represent? You're assigning a value to it as if you want it to represent whether or not a number *is* a prime, whereas the assignment states that the array should contain the prime numbers themselves. Hint: passing in 6 to `isPrime` on every iteration isn't going to help you much either.

Comment: Why do you make `array` an `int[]` when you want to store `boolean`s in it? make it a `boolean[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to add a `boolean` to an `int` array, try the following:

```
int[] primes = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH/2];
int index = 0;
for (int numberList = 1; numberList < ARRAY_LENGTH; numberList++){
    if (isPrime(numberList)){
        primes[index] = numberList;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Now you only check if a number is a prime and ONLY save the prime number to a separate array. the `index` is to keep track of where you are in the list, hence where to add the new found prime number to. The `ARRAY_LENGTH/2` is just a size of whch you can be certain will be long enough.

Comment: By the OP's problem description, I think this is the solution which was intended, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `int[]` Array. The method `isPrime()` is returning a `boolean`. Of course you cannot assign a boolean to an int. This is why you get the error.

Comment: Correct answer - however, `array[numberList] = isPrime(6L);` He is trying to assign a `boolean` to an `int`, not to an `int` array. `array` is an `int` array, `array[numberList]` is just an `int`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple: `isPrime(6L);` returns a boolean value and not an `int` so you need to care a closer look at the design of your application because this is clearly an indication that something is wrong.

Comment: I think you meant `boolean` and `int` not `Boolean` and `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to store the prime number in the array instead of boolean values. I have modified your code to give you the expected result.

**Note:** I have changed your `isPrime` method a bit. Please have a look. Remember `1` is not a prime number, so we start checking from `2` onwards.

```
public class PrimeGenerator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 200;
    int[] array = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    int count = 0;

    for (int numberList = 2; count<200; numberList++)
        if(isPrime(numberList)==true)
        {
            array[count++] = numberList;
        }

    for (int numberList = 0; numberList < count; numberList++)
        System.out.printf("%5d%8d%n", numberList+1, array[numberList]);
  }
  public static boolean isPrime(long number) {
        for (long gg = 2; gg * gg <= number; gg++) {
            if (number % gg == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on your first for statement and why it worked? and how is it different from mine exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem of converting of the boolean into an int like this:

```
public static int convertBooleanIntoInteger(boolean booleanName) {              
    int yourConvertedInteger = 0;
    if(booleanName) {
        yourConvertedInteger = 1; 
    }

    return yourConvertedInteger;
}
```